Java reflection using a specified abstract class or interface
This is the below code that I have.
ServerParams gets its info from a JSON file which is mapped using Jacksons Object Mapper.I haven't put the code here because its quite obvious
IServerParams is an abstract class with a couple of methods which is extended by Server.
setupReflection method is the place where I am doing most of my heavy lifting. The RequestResponse class which has a method doSomething takes in IServerParams as a parameter which is extended by Server.
How do I pass an instance/object of Server to the doSomething method using reflection.
I have tried a number of things and I either get a NoSuchMethodException or ArgumentMismatchException or a NullPointerException. I guess I am missing something obvious.
Please let me know if there is more information that I can provide.
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Data
    public class ServerParams {
       @JsonProperty("server")
       public Server serverparam;

       // More fields 
    }

   @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
   @AllArgsConstructor
   @NoArgsConstructor
   @Data
   public class Server extends IServerParams {
      @JsonProperty("host")
      public String host;
      @JsonProperty("port")
      public long port;

     @Override
     public String getUsername() {
        return "";
     }

     @Override
     public String getPassword() {
       return "";
     }
   }

   public class RequestResponse {
    public void doSomething(final IServerParams iServerParams) {
       final String host = iServerParams.getHost();
       final long port = iServerParams.getPort();
    }
  }

   @Target({ANNOTATION_TYPE, METHOD})
   @Retention(RUNTIME)
   public @interface Configuration {
      @NonNull Class<? extends IServerParams> value();
   }

  public void setupReflection(final ExtensionContext extensionContext, final 
        TestRunner testRunner) {
    final ServerParams serverParams = testRunner.createServerConfig(extensionContext); //creates a new object of serverParams and will contain what the .json file has.

    final Method method = extensionContext.getRequiredTestMethod();
    final Configuration[] configurations = method.getAnnotationsByType(Configuration.class);

    final Class<?> annotationValue = Arrays.stream(configurations)
            .map(Configuration::value)
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow();

    final Field[] declaredFields = serverParams.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

    final Field field = Arrays.stream(declaredFields)
            .filter(type -> type.getType().getTypeName().equals(annotationValue.getTypeName()))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Cannot get instance of the configuration provided"));

    Class<?> classType = field.getType();
    boolean isIt = IServerParams.class.isAssignableFrom(classType);

// everything passes upto here, below is where I am stuck
    if (isIt) {
        RequestResponse requestResponse = new RequestResponse();
        requestResponse.doSomething(field.get); // This is where I am not sure how to 
    }
 }


I don't know if it makes a difference, but maybe you should also mention that you are using lombok ?

So the problem is that you don't know how to use Field.get? Are you unsure about the parameters? It needs the instance of the class that you want to use it on. Also you need to cast the returned value.

@Abra that makes no difference here.

You queried for fields in the serverParams’s class so most probably, you want to read the field from the object, i.e. field.get(serverParams). If you really want to invoke doSomething as shown in the question, a simple type cast will do: requestResponse.doSomething((IServerParams)field.get(serverParams)). This cast will always succeed, in fact, even the test you are doing beforehand are redundant. But is it really what you want? What about the actual annotated Method? Show us the actual code that produced one of the exceptions you said you got.

Side notes: You can simply use final Configuration configuration = method.getAnnotation(Configuration.class); to get the one annotation. No need for a Stream operation here. Then, after a null check, use final Class<? extends IServerParams> annotationValue = configuration.value(); Further, don’t test type equality via type.getType().getTypeName().equals(annotationValue.getTypeName()) Use type.getType() == annotationValue. Since the fields type will be identical to annotationValue, it’s already guaranteed to be assignable to IServerParams. No need for an additional test.

@Holger - the actual annotation in my code is a repeatable annotation. Hence i am using a stream. But i agree about the filtering and can fix it.

Whoever gave the downvote can you explain why?

@Holger, thanks for providing a solution. I can accept your answer. But not sure how to mate, if you would add it as an answer then I can accept your answer.

When it is a repeatable annotation, you need a different strategy than just picking the first one, don’t you? It’s fundamentally whether you, e.g. relax the search to accept a field having a type from one of the annotations or to prioritize fields based on the order of the annotation, if multiple matches exist, or have to invoke the method once for each annotation. Besides that, getting the first element of an array still does not require a Stream operation.

@Holger - yes you are 100% correct. I have changed the design and it is quite different now. Thanks for all the suggestions and clear explanation

A field object just represents the field, not any particular value. Hence, to get the value of that field for some specific instance, you call field.get(someSpecificInstance). It sounds like you want:
Object sfv = field.get(serverFieldValue);


You can get the value and then convert to your Server using
Object serverFieldValue = field.get(serverParams);
Server server = Server.class.cast(serverFieldValue);
requestResponse.doSomething(server);


There is no advantage in using Server.class.cast(serverFieldValue) instead of a straight-forward (Server)serverFieldValue. Besides that, the OP’s requirement is to have a type assignable to IServerParams. The entire point of the reflective operation is avoiding a dependency to the implementation class Server.
